# SpringMVC Different Types of Validation Errors Need to be Supported in Form

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

Our Form Validations errors fall into 2 categories, Primary/Secondary. If there are Primary errors the form can't be saved. For Secondary, the logic is different: it can be saved, but the errors are still displayed for the affected fields.

Currently the Validator logic is implemented in a straightforward manner: a Yes/No decision on whether errors exist in the BindingResult,

```
    @RequestMapping(params="function=save")
    public ModelAndView save(final HttpServletRequest request, 
                                   @ModelAttribute("model") Model model, 
                                   BindingResult bindingResult) {

        ModelValidator.validate(model, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
          System.out.println("Form has minimal errors, not saving";
        }
        else {          
            System.out.println("Form does not have minimal errors, saving ");  
            // Save 
            saveForm(..);
  }
```

Both kinds of errors need to be saved in the request per input field, then displayed in the JSP (but the server-side action is different). How do we distinguish between them? Is there a property we can add to the BindingResult?

Comment: We had a similar scenario. But our architecture was bit different . We used spring validators to validate if  Primary error occurred and to stop any further transaction. The Secondary errors were handled by the business layer as every Secondary error in our case had to be handled separately. Not sure if it helped. I dont think there is any property we can add

Comment: I think the solution is to carry along a custom collection that keeps track of Primary errors, it can reside in an abstract validator that all validators extend, that way we'll have a way of checking if minimal errors exist or not.